# Adding conditions dynamically in php if condtion

Tags: php

I am trying to add a condition dynamically in the if condition . But it is not working . Please help me to fix the issue.

I am trying a code like this

```
 $day_difference = "some integer value";

  if(sheduled_time == 'evening'){
        $condition = '>';
    }else{
      $condition = '==';
    }
```

then

```
if($day_difference.$condition.  0){ 
  echo "something";       
 }else{
   echo "h";
 }
```

Comment: Nice thought, but it doesn't work like that :D

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to gerald's solution; I would suggest that you use a function that validates the inputs using a switch-case operation:

```
function evaluate ($var1, $operator, $var2)
{
    switch $operator
    {
         case: '<': return ($var1 < $var2);
         case: '>': return ($var1 > $var2);
         case: '==': return ($var1 == $var2);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you need is the [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) method.

I.e.

```
$var1 = 11;
$var2 = 110;
$cond1 = '$var1 > $var2';
$cond2 = '$var1 < $var2';
 
if(eval("return $cond1;")){
   echo $cond1;
}
 
if(eval("return $cond2;")){
   echo $cond2;
}
```

**As justly noted beneath, you should exercise the necessary precautions when using this method!**

Comment: `The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.`

Comment: Please be aware that this is very dangerous.

Comment: `If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question` -Rasmus Lerdorf

Comment: You're very right! Just tried to literally answer the question. Added the warning in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the way to do this.
Just define a function which returns `true` if the desired conditions are met.
For example, we can define the function `decide` which receives two arguments, `$day_difference` and `$scheduled_time`:

```
function decide($day_difference, $scheduled_time)
{
    if($scheduled_time == 'evening')
    {
        return $day_difference > 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return $day_difference == 0;
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
if( decide($day_difference, $scheduled_time) )
{ 
    echo "something";       
}
else
{
    echo "h";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

according to your requirements this can be done using the PHP `eval()` function which i don't recommend using it only when necessary.

you can check [When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)

you can use the below script instead:

```
if(  $sheduled_time == 'evening' && $diff > 0 )
{
    echo "This is the Evening and the Difference is Positive";
}
else if($diff == 0)
{
    echo "This is not evening";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for helping me solve my question

I solved this in another way

```
 $day_difference = "some integer value";

 $var1 = false ;
if($sheduled_time == 'evening_before'){ 
    if($day_difference > 0 ){ 
        $var1  = true ;
    }
}else{
    if($day_difference == 0 ){ 
        $var1  = true ;
    }
}

if($var1 === true){ 
  echo "something";       
}else{
  echo "h";
}
```